# Overlay: semi-transparent border, non-transparent inner area - howto

Tags: css

I would like to create an rectangular overlay where the border is semi-transparent and the inner area is not transparent.

If I tweak the `opacity` parameter of the outer `div` (that contains the border) - than all the internal elements become transparent as well, which is unwanted.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of using opacity, if you are alright with using CSS3:

```
border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

That should give you solid red that is 50% transparent. Check out [this intro to rgba](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/) if you want more info.

**EDIT**

If you aren't using an actual border, note that rgba can be used in any place where CSS expects a color, like **background-color**.